# simplification of below sum

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, sum

Is it possible to rearrange/simplify the sum to obtain an expression for k in terms of a:

$\sum_{x=k}^{\infty}{x+n-1\choose x}\theta^n(1-\theta)^x = a $

Comment: I think the above is actually the sum for $\Pr(X>=k)$, X a negative binomial random variable.

Comment: Right: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution for the answer.